# How to copy the hidden field value and pass it on another page using jquery in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am new with CodeIgniter and I want to pass hidden field value to another page using jQuery in CodeIgniter. Can I do this using jQuery?

```
<input type="hidden" name="grdtot" class="grdtot" />
```

this hidden field on cart.php page

```
  <label id="grdtot_c" name="grdtot_c" class="grdtot_c"></label>
```

I want to fetch this hidden field value on checkout.php page. How I can do this using jQuery?

Comment: you can get hidden values by `jquery`. `$('#grdtot_c').val()` and for sending on another page use ajax

Comment: i allready get this value

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this another way using localstorage to getting value from another page

Just write like this on page one.

```
localStorage.setItem('Gridtotal', $('.grdtot').val());
```

And get value from another page.

```
var grdTotal= localStorage.getItem('Gridtotal');
$('#grdtot_c').val(grdTotal);
```

Comment: thanks kunal patel u are solved my issue thanks a lot

Comment: hmmm..You can also remove the value from localstorage using this line localStorage.removeItem('Gridtotal');.

Comment: hello kunal patel can we send the data view to controller using localStorage ????

Comment: You can store the localstorage value in hiddenfield and use it in controller side.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose You have form given below:**

```
<body>
    <div>Upload data to the server without page Refresh</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="hidden_name">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="text" name="website" id="website">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="save" value="Submit">

    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
```

**And Now Your Script to send data to Your Controller**.
You must have to use ajax to send data to the controller in CodeIgniter, And It will make your work easy.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        var hidden_name = $('#hidden_name').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var website = $('#website').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller_name/function_name',
            async:false,
            data:{
                "done":1,
                "hidden_name":hidden_name,
                "name":name,
                "email":email,
                "website":website   
                },
            success:function(data){
                $('#display').html(data);
            }   
        });
    });
});
</script>
```